# How to determine width of peaks and make FFT for every peak (and plot it in separate graph)

Tags: fft, octave

I have an acceleration data for `X-axis` and time vector for it. I determined the peaks more than threshold and now I should find the `FFT` for every peak.
As result I have this:

```
Peak Value 1 = 458, index 1988

Peak Value 2 = 456, index 1990

Peak Value 3 = 450, index 12081
```

....

```
Peak Value 9 = 432, index 12151
```

To find these peaks I used the peakfinder script.
The command **[peakLoc, peakMag] = peakfinder(x0,...)** gives me location and magnitude of peaks. 
Also I have the Time (from time data vector) for each peak.

So what I suppose, that I should take every peak, find its width (or some data points around the peak) and make the `FFT`. Am I right? Could you help me in that?
I'm working in Octave and I'm new here :)

Code:

```
load ("C:\\..patch..\\peakfinder.m");
d =dlmread("C:\\..patch..\\acc2.csv", ";");
T=d(:,1);
Ax=d(:,2);    
[peakInd peakVal]=peakfinder(Ax,10,430,1);    
peakTime=T(peakInd);    
[sortVal sortInd] = sort(peakVal, 'descend');    
originInd = peakInd(sortInd);    
for k = 1 : length(sortVal)     
fprintf(1, 'Peak #%d = %d, index%d\n', k, sortVal(k), originInd (k));    
end    
plot(T,Ax,'b-',T(peakInd),Ax(peakInd),'rv');
```

and here you can download the data http://www.filedropper.com/acc2

FFT

```
d =dlmread("C:\\..path..\\acc2.csv", ";");
T=d(:,1);
Ax=d(:,2);

% sampling frequency 
Fs_a=2000;

% length of FFT 
Length_Ax=numel(Ax);

% number of lines of Fourier spectrum
fft_L= Fs_a*2;

% an array of time samples
T_Ax=0:1/Fs_a: Length_Ax;

fft_Ax=abs(fft(Ax,fft_L));

fft_Ax=2*fft_Ax./fft_L;

F=0:Fs_a/fft_L:Fs_a/2-1/fft_L;

subplot(3,1,1); 
plot(T,Ax); 
title('Ax axis'); 
xlabel('time (s)'); 
ylabel('amplitude)'); grid on;

subplot(3,1,2); 
plot(F,fft_Ax(1:length(F)));
title('spectrum max Ax axis');
xlabel('frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('amplitude'); grid on;
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me: you can't take the the FFT of a peak?? Take the FFT of the whole acceleration data sample is fine, but that's nothing to do with peaks.

Comment: Also, I don't know where you get your `peakfinder` function from. I have Octave 3.8 and it's not there as far as I can see.

Comment: @am304 I have the same Octave, but I don't have the function findpeaks as at moment I have a problem with installation of package with this function. So i just load the peakfinder script.

Comment: @am304 So it's better to make an FFT for the signal? I have to know at what time peaks appear, plot this peaks, and put these pictures with peaks to gps data. And I would like to make spectral characteristic for these peaks.

Comment: so where do you get the peakfinder script then? And "spectral characteristic for these peaks" doesn't make sense, you can only get a spectral characteristic of a signal, not a peak...

Comment: @am304 i've got it here:http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25500-peakfinder/content/peakfinder.m  Anyway it would be preferable to determine the surroundings of peaks and plot them in separate graphics, even without FFT. I'm sure somehow I can get this from peakfinder script, but I'm not good in programming, and still can't understand how it was made in script

Comment: Please include your data and your exact code for finding the peaks in your question.

Comment: @am304 Alright, I've included it to the main question

Comment: @am304 Thanks a lot. It will be useful for further development of program. also I've made the FFT of signal, but I'm not sure is it working right? Can you check my code please. I've added it to the main question again

Comment: I have added how I would go about doing the FFT, I think it's pretty equivalent to what you have done (I haven't studied your code in detail)

Comment: if it helped, please accept and/or upvote the answer so that people who have a similar issue can easily find a solution to their problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have two clusters of peaks, so I would plot the data over three plots: one of the whole timeseries, one zoomed in on the first cluster, and the last one zoomed in on the second cluster (note I have divided all your time values by `1e6` otherwise the tick labels get ugly):

```
figure
subplot(3,1,1)    
plot(T/1e6,Ax,'b-',peakTime/1e6,peakVal,'rv'); 
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(T/1e6,Ax,'b-',peakTime(1:4)/1e6,peakVal(1:4),'rv'); 
axis([0.99*peakTime(1)/1e6 1.01*peakTime(4)/1e6 0.9*peakVal(1) 1.1*peakVal(4)])
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(T/1e6,Ax,'b-',peakTime(5:end)/1e6,peakVal(5:end),'rv'); 
axis([0.995*peakTime(5)/1e6 1.005*peakTime(end)/1e6 0.9*peakVal(5) 1.1*peakVal(end)])
```

I have set the axes around the extreme time and acceleration values, using some coefficients to have some "padding" around (the values of these coefficients were obtained through trial and error). This gives me the following plot, hopefully this is the sort of thing you are after. You can add x and y labels if you wish.

[image]

**EDIT**

Here's how I would do the FFT:

```
Fs = 2000;
L = length(Ax);
NFFT = 2^nextpow2(L); % Next power of 2 from length of Ax
Ax_FFT = fft(Ax,NFFT)/L;
f = Fs/2*linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1);

% Plot single-sided amplitude spectrum.
figure
semilogx(f,2*abs(Ax_FFT(1:NFFT/2+1))) % using semilogx as huge DC component
title('Single-Sided Amplitude Spectrum of Ax')
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
ylabel('|Ax(f)|')
ylim([0 300])
```

giving the following result:

[image]